# How to use org.apache.commons in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT 2.5.0. I want to use some methods in org.apache.commons. GWT want source code also for adding external jar. So I downloaded source and class files and merge both in jar. It is not giving any error for some methods but some classes of org.apache refering other class outside this package. So it gives the following error

```
[ERROR] [rmchecking] - Errors in 'org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java'
[ERROR] [rmchecking] - Line 237: The method isWhitespace(char) is undefined for the type Character
```

Is there any package in gwt that giving same facility of this org.apache.commons? or how to use this same package in gwt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not really possible since StringUtils is based on `java` regular expression and the GWT regular
expression emulator is based on a `javascript`. You will need to write it by your own

Comment: i am assuming u already know com.google.gwt.util.tools.shared.StringUtils

Comment: did GWT giving all facilities like apache.commons?

Comment: Nope bad luck ..not even 20%  :(

Answer (score 11):

You **cannot** use any third party jar that is not GWT compatible. Example **apache-commons**.

**HINT** - They do not have .gwt.xml file telling GWT compiler that they have GWT compatible code.

You can however fork it and make it your own gwt compatible lib from the apache common. Example - http://code.google.com/p/gwt-commons-lang/

Comment: Is there any other jar is using instead of this?

Comment: You can search across google code for such projects. They are poorly maintained and abandoned. We usually take the relevant parts and wrap our own sub-projects :D

Answer (score 1):

I agree with SSR although I wouldn't be surprised if there's some messy debugging involved. It's worth mentioning that there's [gwt-commons](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwtcommons/)
which is still in alpha unfortunately and google guava. I use google Guava, which has a similar purpose to apache commons. It even has some features which apache commons doesn't like Optionals. Guava has a fully functional gwt version created by google that I'm using in my own project.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to convert most of Apache Commons Math 3.6.1 to compile with GWT 2.8.0, see:
https://github.com/murkle/commons-math/issues/1